# XSLT: Blank values after transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do xsl transform: The File Id="" KeyPath="yes" Source=""  has Id and Source blank. I followed other articles and fixed namespaces but still no result.

Original file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmpF22D40156F8E16FBFA89C752FF9D0EF9" Guid="{965AF45C-4B87-44B9-A881-7BEB4CB8D1E1}">
                <File Id="fil2DACDED111D2125FD9BAF52808E5CEB0" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll" />
            </Component>
<Component Id="cmpCEE39BB900F45E2F684F712DD10CEF09" Guid="{FA583F14-6375-42BE-9BB0-046FB8DCB0D1}">
                <File Id="fil51FD07FBBBA9CBF4E0ABE1A9AD93D19C" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\Api.exe" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
     </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmpF22D40156F8E16FBFA89C752FF9D0EF9" Guid="{965AF45C-4B87-44B9-A881-7BEB4CB8D1E1}">
                <File Id="fil2DACDED111D2125FD9BAF52808E5CEB0" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll" />
            </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpCEE39BB900F45E2F684F712DD10CEF09" Guid="{FA583F14-6375-42BE-9BB0-046FB8DCB0D1}"><File Id="" KeyPath="yes" Source="" />
      </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
    </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="InstallFolder"/>
  <xsl:param name="DisplayName"/>
  <xsl:param name="Name"/>
  <xsl:param name="Description"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Set Directory Reference to INSTALLFOLDER (set if required) -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef/@Id">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="$InstallFolder"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- XSL Template to inject WiX service installation elements to a .wxs generated from Heat Project task -->
  <!-- There may be other ways to look for your file -->
  <xsl:template match='wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Component[wix:File[@Source="$(var.BasePath)\Api.exe"]]'>

    <xsl:element name="Component">      
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Guid">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Guid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:element name="File">
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
          <xsl:value-of select="File/@Id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Source">
          <xsl:value-of select="File/@Source"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="ServiceInstall">
    <!-- Service Install -->
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">SERVICEINSTALLER</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="DisplayName">
      <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayName"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Description">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Description"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Start">auto</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Account">LocalSystem</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Type">ownProcess</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="ErrorControl">normal</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Vital">yes</xsl:attribute>

  </xsl:element>
  <!-- Service Control, set as required -->
  <xsl:element name="ServiceControl">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">SERVICECONTROLLER</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Remove">uninstall</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Stop">both</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Start">install</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>       
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your  XML is not well formed: `<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">` does not match `</ComponentGroup>`.

Comment: So, you're geting results for one Component-File node but not for the second Component-File node?

Comment: @DaniAya yes correct

Comment: @michael.hor257k i may have missed it. Real file has lot of <Component>. The one which matches a Source with value "$(var.BasePath)\MircomApi.exe" produces File with empty Id and Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to creating elements is way too complex. Don't use `<xsl:element>` *unless* you are planning to dynamically calculate the element name.

For elements with a fixed name, write out the element. I also shortened the match expression, it does not seem to be necessary to be *this* specific, and introduced attribute value templates.

Your basic error was however that it's not a `File`, but a `wix:File`:

```
<xsl:template match='wix:Component[wix:File[@Source="$(var.BasePath)\MircomApi.exe"]]'>
  <Component Id="{@Id}" Guid="{@Guid}">
    <File Id="{wix:File/@Id}" Source="{wix:File/@Source}" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Looking at your sample some more, I believe that you actually want to copy the elements as they are, *except* when they don't fulfill your condition.

That's much more easily done by writing an empty template for those elements that you want to remove, and use the identity template for everything else. Note the last template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="InstallFolder"/>
  <xsl:param name="DisplayName"/>
  <xsl:param name="Name"/>
  <xsl:param name="Description"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Set Directory Reference to INSTALLFOLDER (set if required) -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef/@Id">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="$InstallFolder"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- any wix:Component that's NOT a match will be suppressed from the output -->
  <xsl:template match='wix:Component[not(wix:File[@Source="$(var.BasePath)\MircomApi.exe"])]' />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```